# Shuffling two lists into each other

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

Given a subset `s` of `Range[n]` and two lists `a` and `b`, with `Length[a]` = `Length[s]` and `Length[b]` = `n - Length[s]`, I would like to construct a new list `shuffle[s,a,b]`, with members of `a` placed at positions given by `s` and members of `b` in the remaining positions, in the same order as in `a` and `b`.

For example, with `n` = 7, `s` = `{2,3,6}`, `a` = `{a1,a2,a3}` and `b` = `{b1,b2,b3,b4}`, `shuffle[s,a,b]` must be `{b1,a1,a2,b2,b3,a3,b4}`.

What comes to my mind is

```
l = Range[n];
Do[l[[s[[k]]]] = a[[k]],{k,Length[s]}];
t = Complement[Range[n],s];
Do[l[[t[[k]]]] = b[[k]],{k,Length[t]}]
```

but most likely there is a much more efficient solution.

Answer (score 10):

```
s = {2, 3, 6};
a = {a1, a2, a3};
b = {b1, b2, b3, b4};

n = Length[a] + Length[b];
list = Range@n;
list[[s]] = a;
list[[Complement[Range[n], s]]] = b;
list
```

> `{b1, a1, a2, b2, b3, a3, b4}`.

Or

```
n = Length[a] + Length[b];
ReplacePart[Range@n, 
 Thread /@ {s -> a, Complement[Range@n, s] -> b} // Flatten]
```

> `{b1, a1, a2, b2, b3, a3, b4}`.

Comment: `Fold[ReplacePart, 
 Range@n, {Thread[s -> a], Thread[Complement[Range@n, s] -> b]}]`

Answer (score 8):

```
a = {a1, a2, a3};
s = {2, 3, 6};
b = {b1, b2, b3, b4};
```

**1.**

We can use one of the many `DataStructures` introduced with V 12.1:

```
ds = CreateDataStructure["ExtensibleVector"];

Scan[ds["Append", #] &, b];

ds["Insert", ##] & @@@ Transpose[{a, s}];

Normal @ ds
```

{b1, a1, a2, b2, b3, a3, b4}

**2.**

Or the more conventional

```
b // RightComposition @@ MapThread[Insert, {a, s}]
```

{b1, a1, a2, b2, b3, a3, b4}

Answer (score 6):

Using **[Ordering](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html?q=Ordering)**:

```
s = {2, 3, 6}; a = {a1, a2, a3}; b = {b1, b2, b3, b4};

#[[ Ordering@Join[s, Complement[Range@Length@#, s]] ]]&@Join[a, b]

(* {b1, a1, a2, b2, b3, a3, b4} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

**Using `Fold`:**

```
n = 7;
s = {2, 3, 6};
a = {a1, a2, a3};
b = {b1, b2, b3, b4};

Fold[Insert[#1, First@#2, Last@#2] &, b, Transpose[{a, s}]]
```

> {b1, a1, a2, b2, b3, a3, b4}

Comment: Great! Although I am sure this is optimal, still let me wait until tomorrow for other versions until accepting.

Comment: There are many ways of accomplishing list manipulation tasks in Mathematica. The 10-way challenge is on.

Comment: What is this 10-way challenge? Never heard of it.

Comment: I believe the trend was started by @Nasser, where participants try to come up with at least 10 ways of solving a stated problem.

Comment: I see. Sounds horrifying...

Answer (score 4):

#### 7.

```
ClearAll[sA]

sA = Module[{i$ = Complement[Range @ Length @ Join @ ##2, #]},
      SparseArray[{# -> #2, i$ -> #3}]] &;
```

***Example:***

```
s = {2, 3, 6}; a = {a1, a2, a3}; b = {b1, b2, b3, b4};

sA[s, a, b]
```

[image]

```
Normal @ sA[s, a, b]
```

> ```
>  {b1, a1, a2, b2, b3, a3, b4}
> ```

#### 8.

```
Normal[SparseArray[s -> a, {Length@Join[a, b]}]] /. 0 :> Last[b = RotateLeft@b]
```

> ```
>  {b1, a1, a2, b2, b3, a3, b4}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

#### 9.

```
a$ = 0; b$ = 0;

Range @ Length @ Join[a, b] /.
   Alternatives @@ s :> a[[++a$]] /. _Integer :> b[[++b$]]
```

> ```
> {b1, a1, a2, b2, b3, a3, b4}
> ```

Comment: This does not work with, say, `a=Array[A,3]`, `b=Array[B,4]`

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, right; it doesn't work if input lists `a` and `b` are not lists of atoms. I will post an update if I figure out a way to make it work for arbitrary lists.

Comment: Would be nice - this version is conceptually very transparent, I would say.

Answer (score 2):

## Timings (cw)

```
|shuf0OP      |0.00746207|
|shufSyed     |0.561942  |
|shufeldo1    |0.707056  |
|shufeldo2    |0.632279  |
|shufcvgmt1   |0.00218898|
|shufcvgmt2   |0.0100496 |
|shufkglr7    |0.00446289|
|shufkglr8    |0.863815  |
|shufvindobona|0.00143314|
|shufkglr10   |0.00182783|
```

Just in case, let me reproduce the way I coded it, in case something is unsatisfactory please let me know (or edit the post accordingly, it is cw after all).

```
funtest[f_, n_, ss_] :=
 Module[{a, b}, 
  Mean[
   First[AbsoluteTiming[f[#, Array[a, Length[#]], Array[b, n - Length[#]]]]]&/@ss
  ]
 ]

n = 10000
ss = Table[Union@RandomSample[Range[n], RandomInteger[n]], {100}];

shuf0OP[s_, a_, b_] :=
 With[{n = Length[a] + Length[b]},
  With[{t = Complement[Range[n], s]},
   Module[{l = Range[n]},
    Do[l[[s[[k]]]] = a[[k]], {k, Length[s]}];
    Do[l[[t[[k]]]] = b[[k]], {k, Length[t]}];
    l
    ]
   ]
  ]

shufSyed[s_, a_, b_] := 
 Fold[Insert[#1, First@#2, Last@#2] &, b, Transpose[{a, s}]]

shufeldo1[s_, a_, b_] :=
 Module[{ds = CreateDataStructure["ExtensibleVector"]},
  Scan[ds["Append", #] &, b];
  ds["Insert", ##] & @@@ Transpose[{a, s}];
  Normal@ds
  ]

shufeldo2[s_, a_, b_] := 
 b // RightComposition @@ MapThread[Insert, {a, s}]

shufcvgmt1[s_, a_, b_] :=
 With[{n = Length[a] + Length[b]},
  Module[{list = Range@n},
   list[[s]] = a; list[[Complement[Range[n], s]]] = b;
   list
   ]
  ]

shufcvgmt2[s_, a_, b_] :=
 With[{n = Length[a] + Length[b]},
  ReplacePart[Range@n, 
   Thread /@ {s -> a, Complement[Range@n, s] -> b} // Flatten]
  ]

ClearAll[sA]
sA = Module[{i$ = Complement[Range@Length@Join@##2, #]}, 
    SparseArray[{# -> #2, i$ -> #3}]] &;
shufkglr7[s_, a_, b_] := Normal@sA[s, a, b]

shufkglr8[s_, a_, b_] :=
 Module[{bb = b},
  Normal[SparseArray[s -> a, {Length@Join[a, b]}]] /. 
   0 :> Last[bb = RotateLeft@bb]
  ]

shufvindobona[s_, a_, b_] :=
 #[[Ordering@Join[s, Complement[Range@Length@#, s]]]]&@Join[a, b]

ClearAll[pA]
pA = Module[{ab$ = Join @ ##2, p$}, 
  p$ = Join[#, Complement[Range @ Length @ ab$, #]]; 
  Permute[ab$, p$]
 ] &;
shufkglr10[s_, a_, b_] := pA[s, a, b]

TableForm@
 Table[{f, funtest[f, n, ss]},
  {f, {
       shuf0OP,
       shufSyed,
       shufeldo1,
       shufeldo2,
       shufcvgmt1,
       shufcvgmt2,
       shufkglr7,
       shufkglr8,
       shufvindobona,
       shufkglr10
      }
   }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

#### 10. (?)

```
pA = Module[{ab$ = Join @ ##2, p$}, 
    p$ = Join[#, Complement[Range @ Length @ ab$, #]]; 
    Permute[ab$, p$]] &;


pA[s, a, b]
```

> ```
> {b1, a1, a2, b2, b3, a3, b4}
> ```

Comment: Why (?)?$\ \ \ $

Comment: b/c I lost count:)

Comment: Seems to be right. I've updated the timings. @vindobona is ahead by few milliseconds (these two solutions must be practically identical, imo)